# menus are hidden behind activeX control

Tags: asp-classic, activex

I have an activeX control on my classic ASP page.  That page also includes a file that contains an asp page that has the toolbar code (just HTML tables/javascript).

What I am finding is that when the toolbar has a dropdown, part of the dropdown gets hidden behind the activeX control.

**This is happening for IE7+**

Any ideas?

```
<div style="left:-25px; width:<%=xyz.xyz.webwidth%>; z-index:20;">
    <div align=left valign=top width="100%" style="background:<%=xyz.htmlcolor%>; border-left: <%=bordersize%>px solid <%=xyz.htmlcolorDark %>; border-right: <%=bordersize%>px solid <%=xyz.htmlcolorDark %>;" >
        <!--#include file="./includes/toolbar.asp"-->
    </div>
</div>

<OBJECT style="z-index:1;" CLASSID="clsid:5220cb21-c88d-11cf-b347-00aa00a28331" VIEWASTEXT>
    <PARAM NAME="LPKPath" VALUE="tx.lpk">
</OBJECT>
<!--TX Text Control -->
<OBJECT classid="clsid:3ce7a701-9bc2-11de-a4c1-0013d350667c" codebase="http://000.000.0.000/web/my.cab" id=objTX  style="width:<%=xyz.yyy.webwidth%>; height:625px; z-index:1">
    <PARAM NAME="ViewMode" VALUE="2">
    <PARAM NAME="ScrollBars" VALUE="3">
    <PARAM NAME="PageWidth" VALUE="12000">
    <PARAM NAME="PageHeight" VALUE="11520">
    <PARAM NAME="AllowDrop" VALUE="1">
    <PARAM NAME="AllowDrag" VALUE="1">
    <PARAM NAME="Text" VALUE="testing">
    <param name="FormatSelection" value="1">
</OBJECT>
```

**I'm still looking for an answer to this...  This is a 3rd party ActiveX control.  We are using classic ASP for this legacy project.**

Comment: is this a problem in all browsers or just some ?  you also may want to google "dropdown menu behind content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shudder making this suggestion, as I thought this had been resolved in more modern versions of IE, but have you tried any of the old shimming techniques?   I remember having to do this for IE 6 and Dropdown select boxes.  [This site](http://www.macridesweb.com/oltest/IframeShim.html) has a pretty good tutorial on it.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work :( - Any other ideas out there?